# What does "lose blunt" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, idioms, idioms-in-context

I am absolutely confused about meaning of "blunt" here. Could not find any card game by this name, no idioms, nothing :( Thank you for you kind help.

Setting: London's gaming hell, 1833.

Nobody knows the real identity of club founder, known as Chase.
The reward is offered. Members of the club are waiting for the reveal.

> “And we have no doubt that very soon, one of you enterprising
> gentlemen will discover the truth about the founder of the Angel.” She
> paused. “Five thousand pounds is, after all, a great deal of money to
> a motley group that **loses blunt** so well.”

"Never Judge a Lady by Her Cover" by S Maclean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is archaic slang for money.  Wiktionary:

> (UK, slang, archaic, uncountable) money
>
> > Charles Dickens, chapter 10, in The Posthumous Papers of the Pickwick Club, published 1837:
> > *Down he goes to the Commons, to see the lawyer and draw the blunt […]*

The word blunt is no longer used in this sense, except as a deliberate use of an old fashioned word.